# Time-Series Forecasting using SVM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series, svm

I want to forecast the next week (horizon = 7) electric load with lag=7 using AR, KNN and SVM, and I need help with that.

I've already wrote a code for all of them and i got results which is not as I expected it should be.

I have a time-series (7160-by-1) and here is a part of my code:

SVM:

Part of Training Data

```
52538   51690   55509   56740   58106   58280   57395
51690   55509   56740   58106   58280   57395   55425
55509   56740   58106   58280   57395   55425   55755
56740   58106   58280   57395   55425   55755   58563
```

Part of Training Targets

```
55425   55755   58563   58705   58245   61880   61540
55755   58563   58705   58245   61880   61540   59791
58563   58705   58245   61880   61540   59791   57945
58705   58245   61880   61540   59791   57945   59198
```

Part of Validate Data

```
101750  97201   98986   99491   99778   99711   100701
97201   98986   99491   99778   99711   100701  102790
98986   99491   99778   99711   100701  102790  98277
99491   99778   99711   100701  102790  98277   99520
```

Part of Validate Data Targets

```
102790  98277   99520   102719  103308  103750  103582
98277   99520   102719  103308  103750  103582  103193
99520   102719  103308  103750  103582  103193  98592
102719  103308  103750  103582  103193  98592   102985
```

Creating SVM model using LSSVM library

```
model = initlssvm(Train_Data,Train_Data_Targets,'f',[],[],'RBF_kernel','o');
model = tunelssvm(model,'simplex','crossvalidatelssvm',{5,'mse'});
model = trainlssvm(model);
```

Predicting future values

```
Estimated_Value = simlssvm(model,Validate_Data(1));
```

but results is not so good, so can you help me ? I can provide the KNN and AR code too is needed.